# Can Go easily emulate the behaviour of Laravel's return Redirect::back()?

Tags: laravel, http, redirect, go, server

While using **Laravel**, I really appreciated being able to use:

```
return Redirect::back();
```

to return to the previous URL after a `POST` request.

Is there a simple in-built way to do this in **Go**?

```
http.Redirect(w, r, backURL, http.StatusSeeOther)
```

where `backURL` is the URL that the POST request was made from.

I've looked through `net/http` and searched SE and google, but I haven't turned anything up. Failing an easy way, I'd appreciate any pointer toward the idiomatic way of doing this in **Go**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Redirect::back()` function uses the URL from the `Referer` HTTP header specified by the client (browser).

You could access this header value like `r.Header.Get("Referer")`, but the [`http.Request`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request) type also provides a direct [`Request.Referer()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.Referer) method that returns the value of this `Referer` field, which also deals with its 2 possible forms (`"Referer"` and `"Referrer"`).

This is how you can mimic the "go back" behavior:

```
func PostHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Process form, then:
    if rf := r.Referer(); rf != "" {
        http.Redirect(w, r, rf, http.StatusSeeOther)
        return
    }

    // No Referer specified, supply your own response
    // or redirect to a default / home page
    http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusSeeOther)
}
```

If you want to call this from many handlers, you may capture this functionality in a helper function:

```
func redirectBack(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if rf := r.Referer(); rf != "" {
        http.Redirect(w, r, rf, http.StatusSeeOther)
        return
    }

    // No Referer specified, supply your own response
    // or redirect to a default / home page
    http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusSeeOther)
}
```

And then using it:

```
func PostHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Process form, then:
    redirectBack(w, r)
}
```

Comment: Awesome answer. This also led me to the `Request` `Referer()` method which allows the compiler to check for the mis-mis-spelling of Referer.

Comment: @PaulParker You're right, using [`Request.Referer()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.Referer) is even better. I'll edit.